# SQL Server Agent 2012 se inicia y se detiene

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy teniendo este problema de que no puedo iniciar SQL server agent 2012, dejo los detalles de mi versión de SQL:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)
- Feb 10 2012 19:39:15
- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

ya estuve revisando las configuraciones del servicio SQL Agent y está en Automático, no se donde puede estar el problema, alguna sugerencia?

influye que anteriormente tenia la version Express y luego hice upgrade a la versión enterprise??
EDIT: Adjunto el log de errores de SQL Agent
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo hiciste la **migración**?  Creo que no puedes hacer *upgrade*  de la versión Express a Enterprise, que hay que hacer copia de las bases de datos, desinstalar la versión Express y luego instalar la versión Enterprise y restaurar las bases de datos. No te hablo desde la experiencia, pero sí lo he leído.

Comment: hola @A.Cedano , el instalador de SQL fui a la opcion "Mantenimiento--> Edition Upgrade" , luego verifique desde SQL haciendo select @@version y me devolvió eso que mostré en el posteo aquí arriba

Comment: ¿Probaste a reiniciar el equipo después? ¿Revisaste que no haya algún SP pendiente de instalación?

Comment: @A.Cedano si ya reinicié la PC pero sigue igual , respecto a los SP no se como verificar eso

Comment: En los avisos de actualizaciones de Windows, verifica que tienes todo actualizado.

Comment: @A.Cedano está todo actualizado

Comment: Convendría que revises el log de errores para saber cuál es el problema exactamente.

Comment: Solo para aclarar que, según el fabricante, es soportado actualizar desde Express hacia Enterprise.

Comment: @A.Cedano adjunto en el post, el log de errores de SQL Agent

Comment: El log de errores es claro: es una cuestión de **permisos**. Quizá al hacer el cambio solo tiene los usuarios/permisos por defecto y debas agregar el usuario actual otorgándole los permisos que sean necesarios.

Comment: @A.Cedano donde puedo cambiar eso??